# Get Facebook User ID By Email Address

Tags: perl, facebook

We have over 10,000 registered users on our site and want to associate each user with a Facebook account with their facebook ID. Our site uses the [WWW::Facebook::API CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Facebook-API/) for all our other Facebook related actions on our site. My question is, is there a method where we can provide a specific user's email address (which they have provided to us during registration) and have the Facebook API return the matching user's Facebook user_id? To be clear we don't want the get the user's email through the Facebook API, but instead want to look them up using their email address. If there is it would be really helpful to see a code snippet of how this would work. Bonus points if this can done through the CPAN module we are already using. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you don't already have the user's facebook user_id, wouldn't this be a privacy violation?

Comment: If you look at the links, it has a number at the end, probably the ID http://www.facebook.com/srch.php?post_form_id=6c854e30c983852bbe5cc7ddd31d19fc&nm=Augusto So it's not privacy violation.

Comment: @Bruno: that's a totally different id than a userid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can.  In a way.

The new [Search API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search) allows you to search publicly available information about users.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mailbox@example.com&type=user
```

As long as the email address you are searching for is public on Facebook (i.e., the user has it set that way in their preferences), it will return the user's name and Facebook ID.

The JSON

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John Doe",
         "id": "123456789"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! Do you know if there is a function that queries this in WWW::Facebook::API so we don't have to go through the hassle of manually authenticating & querying the Search API?

Comment: I'm not a perl guy, sorry.  Is it not documented in any way for you?

Comment: Not the 100% solution I was looking for but got me started in the right direction. Thanks Peter!

Comment: If this is the only solution (for the user to set his email as public). how come rapportive manages to get all public information by email?

Comment: "A user access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: @Nimbuz The Facebook Platform changes quarterly if not monthly. Information that's over two years old (such as this) should be taken with a grain of salt.