# Find Facebook ID using Email address

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to find out user facebook ID and his/her all public profile using email address. Though in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ it was said that it can be found by using:

graph.facebook.com/search?q=shaon@yahoo.com&type=user

where q is user mail address.It's not working. As far as I know it is a bug of facebook. You can check details from here:
developers.facebook.com/bugs/429972587034829 and /274710012636144

I also get some questions from stackoverflow but that there have no description properly.
Like: [Get Facebook User ID By Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250214/get-facebook-user-id-by-email-address)

If anyone can suggest any other link or any other way to do this task than that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a number of test cases. It appears that this query works for your account's friends only. It does not work for friends of friends, page fans (if you're authenticated as a page) or random users.

This is consistent with Facebook's general tightening of privacy controls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not searching after log in. I am searching before log in. So, how it will get any friends. I need to find out any email's Facebook id, public profile without log in into Facebook.